# USB C resistor query

Tags: resistors, usb

If wiring a USB C on the device end (keyboard) with a USB C and the host end(computer) with USB C how do I know which side needs what resistor?

I have read that the device side (keyboard) would use 5.1k, but what would the host side use? Would it also use 5.1k or 56k?

Comment: please read the documentation

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353113/usb-c-connectors-only-work-on-target-side-not-host-side