# Wiring USB 2.0 to USB C Receptacle

Tags: usb, wiring, cables, usb-c

I have a keyboard that uses a USB 2.0 cable to connect to the computer. I would like to remove the current USB 2.0 cable and replace it with a USB C receptacle. The goal is to be able to connect the keyboard to the desktop with a male to male cable (USB C to USB A or C).

My problem is that I cannot find any material discussing the wiring of a USB C receptacle to a USB 2.0 pin out.

In the USB C [spec](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-type-ctm-cable-and-connector-specification-revision-14-march-29-2019) ([Section 3.5.2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/323135/226130)) it illustrates how to wire a USB 2.0 cable with a USB C plug and a USB A plug. Does wiring a USB C receptacle differ from wiring a USB C plug? In other words, can I connect the S/GND/D+/D-/V pin out from my keyboard to a USB C receptacle following Table 3-13 in the spec?

Please let me know if I need to clarify further! I am usually on the software side of things.

**EDIT**

USB 2.0 pin out from keyboard to USB C female receptacle pics

[image: keyboard pinout]
[image: usb c female]

Comment: Nice photo BTW!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fitting an old style USB 2.0 device with new Type-C connector, here is the
[answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/291427/117785)

However, Type-C to Type-C cables are thick, stiff, expensive, and may fall off from a device that is a subject of frequent moving by user. There is a reason why keyboards and mice have non-detachable cables. To use Type-C host ports, you will be much better off if you replace your Type-A plug on your existing flexible cable with Type-C plug. The plug has to have 5.1k pull-down resistor on one of CC pins. Most DIY Type-C plugs offer pre-fabricated pads for this, like in the pictures below:

[image][image]

Comment: I appreciate your concern on durability. It is still unclear to me whether the answer you linked covers wiring the receptacle (not the plug), or whether they are wired the same way regardless.

Comment: Yes, the linked answer is related to a question about wiring the Type-C **receptacle**. On receptacle side you need two pull-down resistors, for each CC pin, although people think that the CC pins can be tied together for USB 2.0-only connector. If making a plug, only one resistor is needed.

Comment: Ah it's all starting to make sense now. Thank you for your patience. Where does the choice to use 5.1k resistor on each CC pin come from? The spec mentions 56k in the cable but this is slightly different.

Comment: @Jtaks, 5.1k comes from specs, it is a pull-down. 56k/22/10k also come from specs, these are the host-side pull-ups.

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15100) looks like it would be perfect for my use case. How ever I am unsure where I would connect the shield pin from the keyboard. Would I wire it to ground? From the linked item's schematic it looks like it is just left unconnected.

Comment: That sparkfun part is missing a shield terminal. it should connect to the body of the socket, so solder to one of the socket's mounting holes.