# USB B to C Receptacle Wiring

Tags: pcb, usb, schematics, kicad, conversion

Hi I am working on a project and my PCB needs to convert from USB 2.0 to a USB C receptacle. Is this wiring correct? I am using this 14 pin USB C receptacle https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2103051834_Jing-Extension-of-the-Electronic-Co.-918-418K2022Y40000_C168704.pdf and created the symbol U1 from that. The two resistors are 5.1k 0.1W. My understanding this power rating doesn't matter too much for these pull down resistors?

[image]

[image: USB C Diagram for Reference]

Comment: The resistors will dissipate about 5mW at 5V - so no, power rating is not an issue!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you have any idea if the rest of the wiring is correct? I spent a long time yesterday trying to work it out and I think its correct as per the instructions in this post. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/291413/usb-c-to-usb-a-pinout/291427#291427

Comment: I believe so but I've never tried this...

Comment: Could you be more precise about "USB 2.0 to USB C" conversion ? What will be on the other side of Type-C cable, and what will be on the other side of USB2 connector (and which type of connector) ?