# Add a USB-C Female socket to NanoPi Neo

Tags: usb, schematics

I'm working on a project which enables two USB ports on the NanoPi Neo core board.

[NanoPi Neo Core pinout](https://wiki.friendlyelec.com/wiki/index.php/File:NEO_Core_pinout-02.jpg)

One is a USB Type-A Female, to connect devices with a regular USB cable, and the other one should be [USB Type-C Female](https://cdn.sparkfun.com//assets/parts/1/3/3/8/3/15111-USB_Female_Type_C_Connector-01.jpg), to use a [USB Type-C Male-Male](https://www.intronics.es/product/image/medium/ew9648_1.jpg) cable to connect devices, NanoPi will act as a Host where we will connect devices.

USB Type-A is easy to connect and it's working ok, but USB Type-C Female only provides power, no connection is stablished.

[This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/323128/wiring-diagram-for-usb-c-to-usb-a-cable) refers to the USB Standard, which points to pull-down with a 5.1k resistor A5 (CC1) pin, which doesn't work, but, in the correct answer, it states to be a USB-C to USB-A conversion diagram, which is not our goal. Anyway, it didn't work.

[This guide](https://www.synopsys.com/designware-ip/technical-bulletin/converting-existing-designs.html), in section *Converting USB 2.0 Device and Host SoCs to USB Type-C*, adds two pull-down 5.1k resistors to both CC pins and that's it, no other changes, but no "connection" to the device.

[This question](https://forum.kicad.info/t/replace-micro-usb-b-receptable-with-usb-c-receptable/17671), which points to the previous link, includes a diagram which illustrates both CC pins to be pulled-down to just replace the connector.

And for the final one, [this link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/291413/usb-c-to-usb-a-pinout/291427#291427) bears out the correct wiring I'm using:

[image: Diagram]

- USB-C GND1 + USB-C GND2 -> NanoPi GND
- USB-C VBUS1 + USB-C VBUS2 -> NanoPi 5vOUT
- USB-C B6 + A6 -> NanoPi USB2_D+
- USB-C B7 + A7 -> NanoPi USB2_D-
- USB-C A5 -> 51k Pulled-Down
- USB-C B5 -> 51k Pulled-Down

This should be the right diagram, but for any reason it's not working.
I'm I missing something?
I'm I using the right diagram?
Is this, use a USB-C Female instead of a USB-A 2.0 Female, doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5k1 pull-downs are used for USB devices, not USB hosts which is what you want to make. Also your schematic has 51k pull-downs which are of course incorrect value for any purpose.

So the first problem is, you need to be Type-C host so you need pull-ups.

But that still is not the correct way to make a Type-C receptacle. If you have a receptacle, you are not allowed to output 5V directly. You must have the VBus disconnected, and only when you detect that there is a device connected, you are allowed to enable the 5V to receptacle.

If you had a Type-C plug then it would be allowed.

It might be best to just put two Type-A receptacles and use standard cables with Type-A plug and Type-C plug.